# changing class to id automatically using jquery

Tags: jquery

Using jquery it is possible to automaticlly change class to id in table.

as example from this bootstrap class

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
```

to css id

```
<table id="mytable">
```

I would like to use the id for my printing page

Comment: Well yes but what logic should be used, Shall it look for a specific class and convert that to the id? or?

Comment: As comment above, you need to define the rules.   Why is it "mytable" and not something else?  Should the bootstrap table classes be removed in all cases?  What if you have 2 tables (they can't both have the same `id`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to select that element using the class selector and add a `id` attribute like:

```
$('.table.table-striped.table-bordered').attr('id','mytable');
```

But if you also want to remove those classes then,

```
$('.table.table-striped.table-bordered').attr('id','mytable').removeAttr('class');
```

`removeAttr('class')` will remove all the class from your `class` attribute and make the element to look like `<table id="mytable">` from `<table class="table table-striped table-bordered">`

Answer (score 1):

You can either use:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered mytable"></table>
$("table.mytable").removeClass("mytable").attr("id","mytable");
```

or

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered"></table>
$("table.table").attr("id","mytable");
```

The first method "converts" the `class` to `id`.
The Second just add an Id to the selected table.